# How could i optimize this code with list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

i have this method which create a list of lists which contain zeros and one.
for example the output for (unit = 3) is: [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
how can i do it in less lines with list comprehension? I think that one line its enough.

```
major_list = []  # contains lists full off zeros and ones and at the end converted to a matrix
for i in range(unit):
    major_list.append([0] * unit)
    major_list[i][i] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get any faster than using `numpy.identity()`:

```
np.identity(3)
```

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np

unit = 3
major_array = np.identity(unit)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a list comphrension you can join 3 sublist

```
major_list = [[0] * i + [1] + [0] * (unit - i - 1) for i in range(unit)]
print(major_list)
```

Or better use a performante way with `numpy`

```
major_list = numpy.identity(3)
print(major_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing the performance of the different methods suggested here, and assuming the required final result is a list of lists (and not `numpy` array), the fastest, with 2.091 seconds to unit = 10k is:

`major_list = [[0] * i + [1] + [0] * (unit - i - 1) for i in range(unit)]`

The numpy method becomes:

`major_list = numpy.identity(unit).astype(int).tolist()`

And is second fastest with 2.359 sec.

My method:

```py
major_list = [[1 if i == index else 0 for i in range(unit)]
    for index in range(unit)]
```

Is far behind with 6.960 sec.

And last:

`major_list = [[int(c==r) for c in range(unit)] for r in range(unit)]`

With 17.732 sec

Answer (score 0):

If by optimize you mean reduce the number of lines (not necessarily make it faster), you can use the following:

```
unit = 4
major_list = [
    [ 0 ] * (i) + 
    [ 1 ] +
    [ 0 ] * (unit - i - 1) 
    for i in range(unit)
]

for i in major_list:
    print(i)
```

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following makes it rather concise:

```
major_list = [[int(c==r) for c in range(unit)] for r in range(unit)]
```

This puts `1` where column index equals row index, `0` everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def frame_matrix(unit):
    return [[int(1)  if i==j else 0 for i in range(unit)] for j in range(unit)]
```